# path planning without using an already made map

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to control (path planning) a robot without sensing environment by any sensor. I mean without using a prepared map.
To do this, I need to set a starting coordination, an end point and coordination of obstacles, then to find the shortest collision-free path by the use of a simple algorithm under ROS environment (A ROS node that calculates the shortest path and command the robot to traverse).
Dose anybody have any idea how to:
1-  Create a so-called hand-made map under ROS package application.
2-  make understand the robot that it has a path ahead without a map?

What else do I need to consider for this simple test? Do I need a special already made ROS package?

I am open to any suggestion, link and information.
Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210115/path-planning-without-using-an-already-made-map/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-05-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This can't be done. You need some kind of sensor on your robot for determining the position of the robot. I also **strongly recommend** sensors for detecting obstacles.

If you do have a way of determining your location (odometry, gps, indoor radio beacons, etc), you could use that in conjunction with a static map to navigate. This approach makes two very dangerous assumptions:

- the map is perfect, and that nothing has moved since the map was made
- the robot knows its location very accurately

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0